# Detecting the platform (Window or Linux) by Groovy/Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, platform-detection

Is there a way to detect the platform (Window / Linux) in which the website is running by Groovy / Grails?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
System.properties['os.name']
```

will return the name of the OS, e.g. "Windows XP". So if you want to figure out whether you're running on Windows or not, you could do something like:

```
if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    println "it's Windows"
} else {
    println "it's not Windows"
}
```

Alternatively, `org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils` (from the [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) project) exposes some boolean constants that provide the same information as the code above, e.g.

```
SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC
SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS
SystemUtils.IS_OS_UNIX
```

More specific constants such as these are also available

```
SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_2000
SystemUtils.IS_OS_SOLARIS
SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX
```

Comment: And in order to get the OS of a Jenkins build node (this is what I was looking for) `System.properties` won't help you since it contains the properties of the Jenkins instance. Instead you can use `onWindows = (env['OS'] ?: "").toLowerCase().contains('windows');`

Answer (score 3):

Or for short:

```
if (System.env['OS'].contains('Windows')){ println "it's Windows" }
```

Since Groovy provides a map access to [`getAt/putAt` methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#getAt%28int%29).