# How to detect the current OS from Gradle

Tags: gradle

I found this answer about how to do it with Groovy:

*[Detecting the platform (Window or Linux) by Groovy/Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689240/how-to-detect-the-platform-window-or-linux-by-groovy-grails)*:

```groovy
if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    println "it's Windows"
} else {
    println "it's not Windows"
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: that's what I use, without the `toLowerCase().contains()` part, as I just need the name.

Comment: You can also get the OS version, with `System.getProperty('os.arch')`

Comment: `"WINDOWS".toLowerCase()` is locale dependent and will return `wındows` (note the dotless i) on machines where the locale is Turkish. Use `toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)` instead to be on the safe side.

Comment: Related: [Gradle Exec for both Mac and PC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27406054/712526)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Actually, I looked at the Gradle project, and this looks a little cleaner as it uses [Ant's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) existing structure:

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

task checkWin() << {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        println "*** Windows "
    }
}
```

I found this in the following Gradle branch, and it seems to work nicely. [gradle/gradle-core/branches/RB-0.3/build.gradle](http://svn.codehaus.org/gradle/gradle-core/branches/RB-0.3/build.gradle)

Comment: be warned, Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX) will return true both for unix and mac (while Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC) is also valid

Comment: Be careful this is indeed the OS and says nothing about the shell gradle got started (e.g. it might be Mingw, Cygwin, or other bash shell). So be careful if you use that to read environment variables, they might not be what you expect.

Comment: @shabunc has a better solution using org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

Comment: `task checkWin() << {` why do you need it? you can just write `if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        println "*** WINDOWS "
    }`

Comment: also it's better to use `org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem` and `if (OperatingSystem.current() == OperatingSystem.WINDOWS)` (if we talk about Gradle why not use their own implementations)

Answer (score 97):

**Mid 2020 Update**:
Still incubating:

```
OperatingSystem os = org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem;
```

**Early 2019 Update**: `current()` removed.

[**`org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.OperatingSystem.getDisplayName()`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/platform/OperatingSystem.html#getDisplayName--)

[**`org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.OperatingSystem.isLinux()`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/platform/OperatingSystem.html#isLinux--)

Keep in mind that it's still [incubating](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Incubating.html) though.

**Mid 2018 Update**: just like it was mentioned in comments, now this class moved to a different package, so one should use [**`org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.OperatingSystem.current()`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/platform/OperatingSystem.html)

---

As of mid 2015, Peter Kahn's answer is still valid. Environment-based profile activation is still something done relatively easier in Maven. But keep in mind that `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os.isFamily` is not exclusive in the sense that if it returns true with one particular parameter it is not necessarily means that it returns false for any other parameter. For instance:

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
task detect {
    doLast {
        println(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS))
        println(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC))
        println(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX))
    }
}
```

It will return true both for `Os.FAMILY_MAC` and `Os.FAMILY_UNIX` on MacOS. Usually it is not something you need in build scripts.

There is though another way to achieve this using Gradle 2+ API, namely:

```groovy
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;

task detect {
    doLast {
        println(OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX())
        println(OperatingSystem.current().isLinux())
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation for the [org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.OperatingSystem](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/platform/OperatingSystem.html) interface. It is worth to mention that this interface is marked with [incubating](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Incubating.html) annotation, that is, "the feature is currently a work-in-progress and may change at any time". The "internal" namespace in the implementation also gives us a hint that we should use this knowing that this can change.

But personally I'd go with this solution. It's just that it's better to write a wrapper class so as not to mess up in case something will change in the future.

Comment: Has it changed? Using Gradle 2.5 `OperatingSystem` doesn't seem to have `.current()`

Comment: mind the internal package: `org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()`

Comment: @danblack how do you get an instance of `OperatingSystem` without `current()`?

Comment: Found one: `OperatingSystem os = org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem`; wish there was a public one @PeterNiederwieser

Comment: Since Mac OS, Windows and Linux are not the only operating systems, it would be nice if z/OS was included.  Although in a pinch, making the choice as not being any of the others could work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be incubating anymore

Answer (score 27):

One can differentiate the **build** environment in between Linux, Unix, Windows and OS X - while the Gradle [nativeplatform.platform.OperatingSystem](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/platform/OperatingSystem.html) differentiates the **target** environment (incl. [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) and [Solaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29)).

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem
OperatingSystem os = OperatingSystem.current();

println "*** Building on ${os.familyName} / ${os.name} / ${os.version} / ${System.getProperty("os.arch")}."

println "*** Building on ${os.toString()}."

if (os.isLinux()) {
    // Consider Linux.
} else if (os.isUnix()) {
    // Consider UNIX.
} else if (os.isWindows()) {
    // Consider Windows.
} else if (os.isMacOsX()) {
    // Consider OS X.
} else {
    // Unknown OS.
}
```

One can also use an Ant task ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784930/549372)):

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

task checkWin() << {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        // Consider Windows.
    }
}
```

Comment: Any clue why does it give me `unable to resolve class org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem
 @ line 5, column 8.`?

Comment: It's still there: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/base-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/os/OperatingSystem.java

Answer (score 10):

Or you can define `osName` as a string...

```groovy
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

switch (OperatingSystem.current()) {
    case OperatingSystem.LINUX:
        project.ext.osName = "Linux";
        break;
    case OperatingSystem.MAC_OS:
        project.ext.osName = "macOS";
        break;
    case OperatingSystem.WINDOWS:
        project.ext.osName = "Windows";
        break;
}
```

... and use it later - to include a native library for example:

```groovy
run {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", "lib/$osName"
}
```

But it wouldn't change anything since OperatingSystem works exactly like your code:

```groovy
public static OperatingSystem forName(String os) {
    String osName = os.toLowerCase();
    if (osName.contains("Windows")) {
        return WINDOWS;
    } else if (osName.contains("mac os x") || osName.contains("darwin") || osName.contains("osx")) {
        return MAC_OS;
    } else if (osName.contains("sunos") || osName.contains("solaris")) {
        return SOLARIS;
    } else if (osName.contains("linux")) {
        return LINUX;
    } else if (osName.contains("freebsd")) {
        return FREE_BSD;
    } else {
        // Not strictly true
        return UNIX;
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/base-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/os/OperatingSystem.java

Edit:

You can do the same for the architecture:

```groovy
project.ext.osArch = OperatingSystem.current().getArch();
if ("x86".equals(project.ext.osArch)) {
    project.ext.osArch = "i386";
}
```

and:

```groovy
run {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", "lib/$osName/$osArch"
}
```

Just be aware that `getArch()` will return:

- "ppc" on PowerPC
- "amd64" on 64b
- "i386" OR "x86" on 32b.

*`getArch()` will return "x86" on Solaris or "i386" for any other platform.*

Edit 2:

Or if you want to avoid any import, you can simply do it yourself:

```groovy
def getOsName(project) {
    final String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    if (osName.contains("linux")) {
        return ("linux");
    } else if (osName.contains("mac os x") || osName.contains("darwin") || osName.contains("osx")) {
        return ("macos");
    } else if (osName.contains("windows")) {
        return ("windows");
    } else if (osName.contains("sunos") || osName.contains("solaris")) {
        return ("solaris");
    } else if (osName.contains("freebsd")) {
        return ("freebsd");
    }
    return ("unix");
}

def getOsArch(project) {
    final String osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch");

    if ("x86".equals(osArch)) {
        return ("i386");
    }
    else if ("x86_64".equals(osArch)) {
        return ("amd64");
    }
    else if ("powerpc".equals(osArch)) {
        return ("ppc");
    }
    return (osArch);
}
```

Comment: The architecture had not been asked for - and reinventing the wheel is useless effort. This may be a personal preference, but most programmers would use an import, whenever an import can be used (using a framework, but not using it, may only produce duplicate code).

Answer (score 8):

Gradle doesn't provide a public API for detecting the operating system. Hence the `os.` system properties are your best bet.

Answer (score 7):

I don't like detecting the OS in Gradle through properties or an Ant task, and the `OperatingSystem` class no longer contains the `current()` method.

So, in my opinion, the cleanest way to detect the OS would be:

Import DefaultNativePlatform:

```
import org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform
```

Then use `DefaultNativePlatform` in your task:

```
if (DefaultNativePlatform.getCurrentOperatingSystem().isWindows()) {
   println 'Windows'
}
```

Mind that this method is not ideal as it is using the Gradle internal API.

It was tested with Gradle 4.10.

Answer (score 2):

Without any imports I got those values from `System` class like here:

```groovy
def osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
def osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
def osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Comment: Doesn't require internal API's.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in **2022/2023** with **Gradle 7.5**

```
import org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform

OperatingSystem os = DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem;

os.isLinux()
os.isWindows()
os.isMacOsX()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @shabunc answer, some of your options are:

1. `org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform`
2. `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os`
3. `org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.OperatingSystem`
4. `org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem`

Number 3 and 4 are basically the same interface, in which `OperatingSystem.current()` is actually `OperatingSystem.isCurrent()` (because of Groovy). So it did not work for me.

Number 2 is a viable option but not that elegant IMHO.

So this is how you can use option 1 (as an example was not included):

```java
import org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform

def os = DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem
def arch = DefaultNativePlatform.currentArchitecture
def version = "1.0.0"

switch (true) {
    case os.windows && arch.i386:
        implementation "com.example:example-win32-x86:${version}"
        break
    case os.windows && arch.amd64:
        implementation "com.example:example-win32-x86-amd64:${version}"
        break
    case os.macOsX && arch.amd64:
        implementation "com.example:example-darwin-x86-amd64:${version}"
        break
    case os.linux && arch.i386:
        implementation "com.example:example-linux-x86:${version}"
        break
    case os.linux && arch.amd64:
        implementation "com.example:example-linux-x86-amd64:${version}"
        break
    default:
        println "No suitable driver found for " + 
                "current OS (${os.displayName}) and " + 
                "architecture (${arch.displayName})"
}
```