# Running grunt with gradle

Tags: cygwin, gradle, gruntjs

I'm having some trouble getting gradle to run grunt. I'm using Windows and cygwin and grunt is clearly in the path:

```
depressio@depressio /cygdrive/c/dev/project
$ which grunt
/cygdrive/c/Users/depressio/AppData/Roaming/npm/grunt
```

So, I make this gradle task:

```
task execGrunt(type: Exec) {
    workingDir './ui'
    commandLine 'grunt'
}
```

Simple enough. However, when I run it, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'grunt''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:195)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:325)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grunt" (in directory "C:\dev\project\ui"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    ... 2 more
```

Why is that? When I go to `./ui` myself, I can run grunt just fine (there is a grunt.js there).

Some suggestions I've found have me defining the `commandLine` as `'cmd', '/c', 'grunt'`, but instead that just opens the grunt.js in an editor. Also, that won't work on UNIX and I'd like this task to work on both Windows (cygwin) and UNIX as long as the PATH is set correctly.

Clearly, I'm missing something.

**Update:**

While this won't work for UNIX, I attempted to use `'grunt.cmd'` instead of simply `'grunt'`. This didn't work either, but gave a different stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'grunt.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:363)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.exec(Exec.java:66)
```

(there's a bunch more, but this is the lowest "caused by")

It does seem to at least execute grunt, however, evidenced by the fact that my coffeescript got compiled into js and this line appeared: `Running "clean:0" (clean) task`

Comment: Are you running the gradle shell script or gradle.bat? If you are running gradle.bat your path may not be inherited from the Cygwin path.

Comment: It's using the shell script. Both run into the same issue, though.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `grunt` in Windows, when I should've been using `grunt.cmd`. Once I did that, and figured out why coffee was failing (why grunt was failing), it seems to work OK.

However, `grunt.cmd` is only for Windows. I did find [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235614/how-to-detect-the-current-os-from-gradle) which provided a way to detect the OS.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: [This article](http://naleid.com/blog/2013/01/24/calling-gruntjs-tasks-from-gradle/) is very timely, and is a much better solution than using my old answer below.

The Gradle developers might hate me for this, but I don't use the `Exec` task, I do this instead:

```
task execGrunt {
    doLast {
        println "grunt".execute().text
    }
}
```

See [Groovy docs for external processes](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy) for more. BTW, the reason for your latest failure is Grunt returned an exit code saying it failed (non-zero).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gradle plugin:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.moowork.grunt