# How do you support a Gradle Exec task for both Mac and PC?

Tags: windows, macos, gradle

Is there a way to be able to execute a task on both Windows and Mac if the commands take a different form? For example:

```
task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {

    // use this command line if on Windows
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'stop.cmd'

    // use the command line if on Mac
    commandLine './stop.sh'
}
```

How would you do this in Gradle?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can conditionally set the `commandLine` property based on the value of a system property.

```
if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows')) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'stop.cmd'
} else {
    commandLine './stop.sh'
}
```

Comment: BTW, I found (at least for Windows 8.1) that the string returned is "Windows 8.1" (capital W). So you need to either use .contains('Windows') or even better, System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows') will cover differences in case.

Comment: Or you do `import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;` and then `OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()`

Comment: I'd suggest not using internal classes as they are bound to change without notice.

Comment: The OperatingSystem API is now public, `org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/platform/OperatingSystem.html

Comment: FYI, the link above is to an interface. The implementation for that interface is still internal so there's no way to realistically use it without again depending on internal classes.

Comment: There's an Ant library to check the operating system. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784930/712526

Answer (score 9):

If the script or executable were the same on windows and linux then you'd be able to do the following so that you only have to define the arguments once by calling a function like so:

```
       import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os       

       task executeCommand(type: Exec) {    
            commandLine osAdaptiveCommand('aws', 'ecr', 'get-login', '--no-include-email')
       }

       private static Iterable<String> osAdaptiveCommand(String... commands) {
            def newCommands = []
            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                newCommands = ['cmd', '/c']
            }

            newCommands.addAll(commands)
            return newCommands
       }
```

Comment: I find this solution more elegant and makes for less clutter if several command line calls are done. Needs more upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

I referred to here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31443955/1932017

```java
import org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform

task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {
    if (DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem.isWindows()) {
        // use this command line if on Windows
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'stop.cmd'
    } else {
        // use the command line if on Mac
        commandLine './stop.sh'
    }
}
```