# Can't run ndk-build on Android studio from gradle on osx yosemite

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I am trying to run ndk-build from my build.gradle in an Android Studio 1.0 project on MAC OSX Yosemite.

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath

}
```

I have specified the ndk-dir in the local.properties file but I am getting this error

```
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build'
```

If I run the gradle script from command line like this everything successfully builds

```
./gradlew :myproject:assembleDebug
```

So for some reason the IDE is unable to call ndk-build. I enabled some debug info in 
Android studio and I have the following error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

So the IDE cannot find the ndk-build exe however running from the terminal inside the IDE the ndk-build exe can be found.

Thanks

Comment: Well I have a workaround for now, the IDE can't find the path to ndk-build so I put the full path in commandLine 'fullpath/ndk-build' then it works

Comment: Did you set Android Studio to use the Gradle wrapper?

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT**

You can now retrieve the path like this :

```
android.ndkDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
```

I updated the sample below.

---

As you said in the comments, `commandLine` requires the path of ndk-build program to make it work. Here is a way to retrieve the ndk path in build.gradle :

```
// call regular ndk-build script from app directory  
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory.getAbsolutePath()

        commandLine ndkDir + "/ndk-build", '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    }
```

You will have a "cannot infer argument type" lint warning, You can safely ignore this warning. Add `// noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck` to get rid of it.

This was tested with gradle 1.2.3

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for this ndkDir trick! However, I had to write ```commandLine ndkDir+'/ndk-build.cmd' ```

Comment: The right way to get the ndkDirectory is to use android.ndkDirectory

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't need to convert to absolutePath, relative is just fine

Comment: @PhilLab: that's because you are on Windows. The good practice is to check at runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27406803/192373