# Changing properties in Grails 3 application yml file through gradle

Tags: grails, gradle

There are some properties that I have in the default generated application.yml file in Grails 3. Take for example this property

```
test:
    network:
        path: '/home/cool/testing_data'
```

Now, the part that I want to do is change this property when I invoke the build script, so that it is different for the various OS that it might be executed on. I.e: On windows, that path should be 'E:/shared/testing_data', and on solaris, something different.

Using this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235614/how-to-detect-the-current-os-from-gradle), I can conclude that I can identify which OS I am currently on, so that I can potentially make some changes. Ex:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
task checkWin() << {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        // it is windows, lets change the path to not be linux like
    }
}
```

So my question is, using gradle or any other means as necessary, can I change the properties in application.yml file to accommodate the different OS systems that the application might be deployed on? I am considering reading the application.yml file line by line and doing a string replacement, but I will resort to this only if there are no cleaner solutions.

Maybe am I using the wrong tool to solve this problem as is, so a good question to ask is, is there an easier way that I am missing here, possibly a similar approach to different "environments" like :test, dev, prod, for operating systems, already built into the core functionality of grails that I can re-use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create `application.groovy` file in the same folder as `application.yml` is. In groovy file you can use any script to set value of properties.

For example add this line to `application.groovy` file (also remove option from yml):

```
test.network.path = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'd:\something' : '/home/something'
```