# Checking for Windows 7 Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Wanted to create a script that is able to check the specific OS of a system. There are ways to find the aliases "Windows", "Linux", etc ([How to detect the current OS from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235614/how-to-detect-the-current-os-from-gradle/31443955)), but this is not enough. But I need to specifically check the full version to determine whether it is Windows 7 or not.

Answer (score 0):

You check the version as well , the windows 7 will return 7 as version like this

```
tasks.register('CheckSystemVersion') {
    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        println System.properties['os.name']
        println System.properties['os.version']
    } else {
        println "it's not Windows"
}}
```

for more info about possible os you can check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Apache Commons Lang to the build and use `SystemUtils`:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    }
}

tasks.register('checkWindowsVersion') {
    doLast {
        println SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_7
    }
}
```